# codeigniter update issue You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting the error when I am updating

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 = Array WHERE `order_id` = '11'' at line 1

UPDATE `rel_orders_prices` SET 0 = Array WHERE `order_id` = '11'

Filename: modules/admin/models/Booking_model.php

Line Number: 241

Comment: Your column name not proper in the query. (Add your code)

Comment: $this->db->set($save_price);
$this->db->where('order_id',$id);
$this->db->update('rel_orders_prices');

Answer (score 0):

You should use backticks for the column name, because it contains only numbers and the value should be within quotes, so this should work:

UPDATE rel_orders_prices SET `0` = 'Array' WHERE order_id = '11'

**Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.**

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this like,

```
$this->db->set('save_price',$save_price);
```

Because column name missing.

If array then,

```
$this->db->set(array('save_price'=>$save_price));
```

OR

```
$this->db->update('rel_orders_prices',array('save_price'=>$save_price));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query in your model file.

```
function update($order_id,$insertArray){
return $this->db->where('order_id', $order_id)->update('tablename',$insertArray);
}
```